# Python networkx graph: Do not draw old graph together with new graph

Tags: networkx

The below is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
for i in range(2):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    if i==0:
        G.add_edge("A", "B")
    elif i==1:
        G.add_edge("A", "C")
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    nx.draw(G)
    plt.savefig(str(i)+".png")
    G.clear()
```

It should draw line AB in file 0.png and draw line AC in file 1.png. But, after I ran it. In 0.png, there is one line AB, but in 1.png, there are two lines: AB and AC. It seems that the memory for 0.png is not cleaned, although I have had "G.clear()".

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I have got the solution. Add "plt.clf()" after "plt.savefig(str(i)+".png")". It can clean old graph in the pyplot. I hope it can help anyone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have got the solution.

Add `plt.clf()` after `plt.savefig(str(i) + ".png")`. It can clean the old graph in pyplot. I hope it can help someone.