# How to update a NetworkX plot in real-time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to update a networkx plot using matplotlib in a canvas, but it adds a new plot to the graph each time instead of updating the graph below, I had to add the call to `nx.draw_networkx()` function to get it to update and I'm not sure if this is part of the issue.
Example Code:

```
import psutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg
)

root = Tk()
root.title("Hello")

mlist = psutil.net_connections(kind="all")
fig = plt.figure(frameon=True, figsize=(5,1), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
Node = nx.Graph()

for v, val in enumerate(mlist):
    if val[4] != () and val[4][0] != "127.0.0.1":
        print(str(val[4][0]) + " - " + str(val[6]))
        print(psutil.Process(val[6]).name())
        Node.add_node(str(val[4][0]))
        Node.add_edge(str(val[4][0]), "localhost")

plt.gca().set_facecolor("grey")
fig.set_facecolor("black")

nx.draw_networkx(Node, pos=nx.spring_layout(Node, 25), alpha=1,
                 with_labels=False, node_size=100, node_color="green")

canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

def Add():
    Node.add_node(str("LOL"))
    nx.draw_networkx(Node, pos=nx.spring_layout(Node, 25), alpha=1, 
                     with_labels=False, node_size=100,
                         node_color="blue")
    canvas.draw()

ex = tk.Button(root, text="Update", command=lambda: Add())
ex.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a similar question and answer after a lengthy search on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812996/python-networkx-graph-do-not-draw-old-graph-together-with-new-graph) however for clarity and because i also used code from elsewhere you must use the `G.clear()` to clear the current nodes and edges from the graph.
`plt.clf()` to clear the figure from the canvas followed by `canvas.draw` to draw the new or update graph onto the canvas.

The use of the 3 functions above will depend on your individual use.