# How to update a networkx drawing

Tags: python, networkx

I would like update my networkx plot in real-time. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794523/how-to-update-a-networkx-plot-in-real-time) but it doesn't seem to help or I have misunderstood it. Here is my MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
import time

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)

colors = ['r']*len(T.nodes)
for i in range(31):
    colors[i]='y'

pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="dot")

# Use this instead if you don't have dot installed
# pos = nx.spring_layout(T)

nx.draw(T, pos, node_color=colors, edge_color='#909090', node_size=200, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
time.sleep(1)
plt.clf()

T.remove_edge(3,8)
T.add_edge(3,4)
T.add_edge(7,8)
nx.draw(T, pos, node_color=colors, edge_color='#909090', node_size=200, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

If you run this you get one image in a window, then you have to kill the window and the second image appears in a new window. I would like it to be updated in the existing window without having to interact with it at all.

How can you do that?

Comment: When I try to run your code, it throws the following error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path.`. Is it even possible for to run your code?

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam it needs "dot" to be installed which comes from graphviz. If you replace "dot" with "twopi" does it work for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam you can replace the "pos" line with `pos = nx.spring_layout(T)`. It won't be as pretty that doesn't matter for my question.

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope that answers your question. 

Comment: You're very welcome 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.clf()` doesn't work in this situation. When the `plt.show()` is runned it will only wait for an interaction to close it, and it won't change.
You should make the changes and delays before the `plt.show()`
Use `plt.pause()` instead.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
import time

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)

colors = ['r']*len(T.nodes)
for i in range(31):
    colors[i]='y'

pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="dot")

# Use this instead if you don't have dot installed
# pos = nx.spring_layout(T)

nx.draw(T, pos, node_color=colors, edge_color='#909090', node_size=200, with_labels=True)

plt.pause(1)   # <------ it will pause for 1 second 

T.remove_edge(3,8)
T.add_edge(3,4)
T.add_edge(7,8)
nx.draw(T, pos, node_color=colors, edge_color='#909090', node_size=200, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```